# OpenMP support on OpenBSD

Tags: compiler-errors, g++, openmp, openbsd

I'm trying to build [Crypto++](http://www.cryptopp.com/) on OpenBSD 5.7 x86_64 with OpenMP support. The compile is failing with the error message:

> ```
> g++ -DDEBUG -g3 -Os -fPIC -fopenmp -march=native -DCRYPTOPP_DISABLE_SSS3 -c nbtheory.cpp
> nbtheory.cpp: error: omp.h: No such file or directory
> ```

OpenBSD's compiler clearly supports the `-fopenmp` option (another 150 files compile OK with the flag), so I'm not sure what I should do.

I have the OpenSBD sources and ports installed, but I'm not able to find the header:

```
$ find / -name omp.h 2>/dev/null
$
```

I tried Googling, but it turned up a bunch of evasive answers about OpenMP support. See, for example, [OpenMP with gcc4?](http://openbsd-archive.7691.n7.nabble.com/OpenMP-with-gcc4-td58791.html).

Do I need to install it from somewhere? Or does OpenBSD just not support it?

If I need to compile/install the library proper from somewhere, where do I find it?

Comment: What is 'gcc -v' on your machine?

Comment: @Jeff - `gcc --version` returns `4.2.1 20070719`. I think the OpenBSD folks froze GCC due to licensing changes by GNU to combat [Tivoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tivoization). Regardless, `gcc` responds to `-fopenmp`, which implicitly declares support for OpenMP. Using an option like `-ffoobar` results in a compile error. I'm beginning to think something is wrong with the OpenBSD port.

Comment: Just build GCC 4.9+ from source. I see no reason why this shouldn't work. Latest Clang/LLVM supports OpenMP as well.

Comment: A more recent link than what you found yourself, http://marc.info/?l=openbsd-misc&m=140454992125167&w=2 looks like it's not supported.

Comment: Thanks @ci_. I filed a bug report because the compiler accepted `-fopenmp` and even defined `_OPENMP` in response to the option: [GCC cannot compile an OpenMP program](https://marc.info/?l=openbsd-bugs&m=143436095812233).